# No , logro sacar el promedio

Tags: python, python-3.x

en la parte del promedio , me sale que no puede ser dividido por 0, pero no entiendo porque el valor no se cambia de 0, podrian ayudarme?, gracias, solo me hace falta sacar el promedio de las 4 sedes, tener un promedio total de las 4 sedes, o el promedio total de cada sede , muchas gracias, cualquiera de las 2 formas de promedio , seria genial.

No entiendo porque el contador no suma los valores , si me podrian explicar esa parte tambien , seria genial.

```
a = []
b = []
promedio = 0
promedio2 = 0


dias = 7

for z in range(dias):
    a.append([0] * 2)
    b.append([0] * 4)


for i in range(dias):
    print ("||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||")
    a[i] = str(input("Escriba los dias de la semana en orden(ejemplo:lunes,marte...): "))
    for j in range(4):

        print ("||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||")
        b[i][j] = int(input("Escriba las ganancias correspondientes a este dia , (sede 1 - 4):"))
        while (b[i][j] <= 0):
            b[i][j] = int(input("Escriba un numero positivo mayor a cero : "))
print("")        
for i in range(dias):
     print(a[i],"  ", end=" || ")
     print("",end=" ")
     for j in range(4):
        print("$",b[i][j],"SEDE",1+j, end=" || ")
     print("")
print("")

for j in range(dias):
    menor = 100000000000000000000000000000000000000
    mayor = -100000000000000000000000000000000000000
    for i in range(4):
        if (b[j][i] <  menor):
            menor = b[j][i]
        if (b[j][i] >  mayor):
            mayor = b[j][i]
    print( "menor ganancias en las 4 sedes correspondiente al dia :",a[j],"= $",menor,"pesos")
    print ("=================================================================================")
    print( "mayor ganancias en las 4 sedes correspondiente al dia :",a[j],"= $",mayor,"pesos")

print("")

while True:

    print("Escriba (1) para saber el promedio")
    print("Escriba (2) para salir")    
    print("")
    opcion  = int(input("Digite su eleccion : "))
    print("")
    if (opcion == 1):
        sede= int(input("Escriba la sede que quiere saber el promedio : "))
        print("")
        c = sede - 1
        suma = 0
        contador = 0
        for i in range(dias):
            if (b[i][c] <= 50):
                if (b[i][c] >= 30):
                    contador += 1 
                    suma = suma + b[i][c]

        promedio = suma / contador
        print("") 
        print("El promedio de los dias entre 30 y 50 millones son :",promedio)
        print("")


    if (opcion == 2):
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes en cuanta para el promedio aquellos valores entre 50 y 30 (ambos incluidos) a causa de los dos condicionales. Si no hay ningún valor entre este rango `promedio = suma / contador` será igual a `promedio = 0 / 0`.

Si solo quieres calcular el promedio para este subconjunto de valores, usa un condicional para controlar la situación en la que no exista ningún valor en dicho intervalo:

```
if (opcion == 1):
    sede= int(input("Escriba la sede que quiere saber el promedio : "))
    print("")

    c = sede - 1
    suma = 0
    contador = 0
    promedio = 0

    for dia in b:
        if 30 <= dia[c] <= 50:
            contador += 1 
            suma += b[i][c]

     if contador != 0:
         promedio = suma / contador
```